# Can Apache spark by itself choose the machine learning model based on the data? If yes, how?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I heard someone saying spark can choose its machine learning model based on the data. But didn't find any posts related to it. Can Spark really choose the machine learning model based on our data? If yes, How do we do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, it provides api's to train, test and apply models, but you have to do the work of actually selecting and building the model.  I expect in the right circumstances you could even use spark to build a model that chooses between trained models.  But it's on you to build this stuff, spark is just the platform.